# Does model binding send every id and value of a control within a form to the post action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

As I have some unworking stuff here I would like to know to make sure that every controls id + value which are placed in a form are sent to the POST action if the parameters have the same names.

Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard HTML form POST will send the `name` and `value` of each `<input>`, and `<textarea>` element, along with the value of the selected `<option>` in a `<select>` box. If a submit button caused the form post, that button's name and value will also be sent.

In many cases in ASP.NET MVC, the `name` will be the same as the `id`, but that is not always the case.

The easiest way to tell whether a value is getting sent to the server is to examine the post in the Network tab of Firebug or Chrome's developer tools.

Comment: Does that mean I have to put some values into hidden fields by using the Html.HiddenFor() helper? This sounds like ViewState 2.0 ;-)

Comment: Note that if the input type is `checkbox`, then it will *not* post the name or the value at all if it is unchecked. As far as a POST is concerned, there is no difference between an unchecked checkbox and no checkbox at all.

Comment: @Elisa: Au contraire: if those values were *automatically included* in hidden fields without your intending to put them there, then it would be ViewState 2.0. Requiring you to specify which values you actually care to persist (and bind) with each request is a nice, big step away from the WebForms paradigm.

Comment: Warrior... ok you are right. I just used the Html.HiddenFor and it does its job in the action parameter...